# helper function in R

Tags: r, helper, tidyselect

I am trying to replace NA with 0 for some specific variables irrespective of their positions. i wrote below code, but getting some error..

```
data1[, starts_with("Year_")][is.na(data1[, starts_with("Year_")])] <- 0
```

i got the below error

```
Error: No tidyselect variables were registered 

Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

I have installed `dplyr`, `tidyr`, `tidyselect`, but still i am getting this error, can anyone help me on this matter.

Comment: If you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610), you could make it easier for others to find and test a answer to your question. That way you can help others to help you!

Comment: If you are using base R try `startsWith("Year_", names(data1))`. the tidyhelper `starts_with()` is typically used within the `select()` function within a pipe sequence `%>%`

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide a MRE i had to create it myself:

```
df<- data.frame(id = 1:5,
                Prefix_1 = c(1, 2, 3, NA, 5),
                Prefix_2 = c(NA, 1, 2, 3, NA))
```

Solution, how to replace `NA` with **fictional** data:

```
df[, grepl("^Prefix_", names(df))][is.na(df[, grepl("^Prefix_", names(df))])] <- 0
```

df is now:

> ```
>  id Prefix_1 Prefix_2
> 1  1        1        0
> 2  2        2        1
> 3  3        3        2
> 4  4        0        3
> 5  5        5        0
> ```

Just be aware that only because we *can* replace `NA`s with `0` doesn't mean we *should*. I assume you have an excellent reason *why* `NA`s should be `0` ;)

## Edit:

Solution with `dplyr`:

```
df<- data.frame(id = 1:5,
                Prefix_1 = c(1, 2, 3, NA, 5),
                Prefix_2 = c(NA, 1, 2, 3, NA))


library(dplyr)   
df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(matches("^Prefix")), coalesce,  0)
```

Or, using `dplyr` and `tidyr::starts_with`:

```
library(dplyr)   
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Prefix")), coalesce,  0)
```

Comment: Hi Dario,  i used                                                                                                               df[, grepl("^Prefix_", names(df))][is.na(df[, grepl("^Prefix_", names(df))])] <- 0 ; and it worked ... thanks... :)